# Im having trouble linking SDL libraries

Tags: c++, makefile, sdl

I'm creating a makefile for my 2D sandbox game and when I compil the final executable file, the linker doesn't recognize all the SDL functions.

./libs -> all SDL libraries (SDL2.lib, SDL2test.lib, SDL2_ttf.lib)
./include -> all SDL classes and functions

```
#variables
SRC_DIR = .
LIBS = -Llib/SDL2 -Llib/SDL2main -Llib/SDL2test -Llib/SDL2_ttf
INC = -Iinclude
BIN = theGame
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -pedantic -Wall
RM = rm

#make
theGame: main.o Block.o Character.o FileAccess.o GameObject.o Item.o Ladder.o NPC.o Player.o Window.o World.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(BIN) main.o Block.o Character.o FileAccess.o GameObject.o Item.o Ladder.o NPC.o Player.o Window.o World.o $(LIBS)

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC) $(SRC_DIR)/$^

Block.o: Block.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC) $(SRC_DIR)/$^

Character.o: Character.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC) $(SRC_DIR)/$^

FileAccess.o: FileAccess.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC) $(SRC_DIR)/$^

GameObject.o: GameObject.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC) $(SRC_DIR)/$^

Item.o: Item.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC) $(SRC_DIR)/$^

Ladder.o: Ladder.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC) $(SRC_DIR)/$^

NPC.o: NPC.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC) $(SRC_DIR)/$^

Player.o: Player.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC) $(SRC_DIR)/$^

Window.o: Window.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC) $(SRC_DIR)/$^

World.o: World.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC) $(SRC_DIR)/$^
```

> g++ -pedantic -Wall -o theGame main.o Block.o Character.o FileAccess.o
>   GameObject.o Item.o Ladder.o NPC.o Player.o Window.o World.o
>   -Llib/SDL2 -Llib/SDL2main -Llib/SDL2test -Llib/SDL2_ttf main.o: In function `pollMenuEvents(Window&)': main.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined
>   reference to`SDL_PollEvent' main.o: In function `pollEvents(Window&,
>   std::vector<Character*, std::allocator<Character*> >&, World*)':
>   main.cpp:(.text+0xae): undefined reference to`SDL_PollEvent' Block.o:
>   In function `Block::draw(int, int) const': Block.cpp:(.text+0xf4):
>   undefined reference to`SDL_SetRenderDrawColor'
>   Block.cpp:(.text+0x10b): undefined reference to `SDL_RenderFillRect'
>   Ladder.o: In function`Ladder::draw(int, int) const':
>   Ladder.cpp:(.text+0x19a): undefined reference to
>   `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor' Ladder.cpp:(.text+0x1b1): undefined reference
>   to`SDL_RenderFillRect' Ladder.cpp:(.text+0x22e): undefined reference
>   to `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor' Ladder.cpp:(.text+0x245): undefined
>   reference to`SDL_RenderFillRect' Ladder.cpp:(.text+0x2dd): undefined
>   reference to `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor' Ladder.cpp:(.text+0x2f4):
>   undefined reference to`SDL_RenderFillRect' NPC.o: In function
>   `NPC::draw(int, int) const': NPC.cpp:(.text+0xbd0): undefined
>   reference to`SDL_SetRenderDrawColor' NPC.cpp:(.text+0xbe7): undefined
>   reference to `SDL_RenderFillRect'

.
.
.

Comment: Are the various SDL libraries in `lib` or `libs`?

Comment: Are you using the proper libraries for your architecture?

Comment: @SilvanoCerza they are in `lib`.. I only messed up the description of the problem, there should be `./lib`.

Comment: @Yastanub Yes, I believe so, I developed my game on Windows and It works. Now Im just trying to compile it in Linux for my school homework.

Comment: Do you use 64 bit(x86_64/amd64) or 32 bit libraries(i386)?

Comment: @Yastanub Im using x86 libs. I see, but my Ubuntu is 64bit, is that the problem?

Comment: It only depends what architecture your built binary is using.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
LIBS = -Llib/SDL2 -Llib/SDL2main -Llib/SDL2test -Llib/SDL2_ttf
```

To:

```
LIBS = -Llib -lSDL2 -lSDL2main -lSDL2test -lSDL2_ttf
```

---

The compiler rules are not entirely correct because the source file directory is missing in the prerequisites (they only work because `SRC_DIR` is `.`).

All those compiler rules can be replaced with one pattern rule:

```
%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) -o $@ -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC) $^
```

Comment: I made those changes and the situation improved. Now the linker successfully linked most of the functions, but it still have a problem with -lSDL2test .. When I try to make, it says `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL2test` which is weird because it should be installed as well during `apt-get install libsdl2-2.0`

Comment: @Mig1-5 You need to install the _development_ libraries, e.g. `apt-get install libsdl2-dev` (or whatever it is called). The one you installed doesn't provide the _unversioned_ symlinks, so that `ld` doesn't find it.

Comment: I already have development library, it says I have newest version, do you think I should reinstall or something?

Comment: @Mig1-5 Are you sure that `SDL2test` is a library, where does it come from?

Comment: Recently, I found out that it is a support library for debugging and my program can run without it. I have done some changes to my makefile and it works. Thanks for your effort :]